# Copy object and change nested property in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this kind of object in data:

```
data () {
return {
    foo: {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: {title: "Main"}};
}}
```

I need to get exact copy of this object but change one thing there

```
foo2:  {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: {title: "Copy"}};
```

I tried setting `foo2` in data as:

```
foo2: {...foo, c['title']:'Copy'},
```

But Im getting error:

```
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread `foo` into its own object with a `c` property with a value of an object. Then spread `foo.c` into this object, which you can add the `title` property to like so:

```
foo2: {...foo, c: {...foo.c, 'title':'Copy'}
```

Spreading `foo.c` will allow any additional own enumerable properties (if any) from `foo.c` to remain in the new `c` object value.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo2: {...foo, c: {...foo.c, title: 'Copy'}},
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it？

```
const foo2 = { ...foo, c: { title: "Copy" } }
```

Comment: `c: {...foo.c, title: "Cody"}` is probably better since `c` can have multiple properties

Answer (score 0):

Will it work?

```js
const foo = {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: {title: "Main"}}

const foo2 = { ...foo, c: { ...foo.c,  title: 'Copy' } }

console.log(foo2)
```

Comment: `c: {...foo.c, title: "Cody"}` is probably better since `c` can have multiple properties